# How to export Application.Current with MEF in SL3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, mef, dynamically-loaded-xap

I seem to be stuck. 
Is there a way to export Application.Current of a Silverlight project using MEF, so that when I load .XAP (my Silverlight component project) file I had access to the App of that .xap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a need for this.  Since [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is already a singleton, it's going to exist once your .xap is loaded in any case.  You shouldn't need to export it via MEF - your component will already be able to access it directly.

Comment: I'm really new to MEF, so sorry if my question seems silly. I'm still trying to resolve the [following problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182917/application-startup-doesnt-get-called-when-i-load-xap-dynamically-with-mef). When I call Application.Current, I get access to the mail App, that dynamically loads my .xap, not the imported one

Comment: @Masha: There is only a single Application.Current at a time in an application.  If you're dynamically importing a xap that's intended to be run standalone, it's "application" startup logic won't execute.  You should refactor that into something where you can explicitly call it post-composition, if that's your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Container.ComposeExportedValue(Application.Current);
```

where `Container` is MEF's `CompositionContainer`.